# How to use Interactive documentation for Python in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, kite

I want to have access to the documentation of different python libraries as soon as I pose my mouse in their function and classes, using Python code in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: You want to install plugins for that;

Comment: who downvoted this?

Comment: This question belongs on [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to download Kite, you don't need to directly install any plugin:

- Hey team! I've been using Kite, an AI-powered Python autocompletion engine, to boost my productivity. You can get it for free at https://kite.com.
  Check it out in action! https://gph.is/g/apmXP3Z

Alternately you could use the Anaconda plugging, here how to install it:

- http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/

You can also use them together deactivating Anaconda's autocompletion and taking the best benefits of Anaconda plugin (IDE features and autopep8 formatting) and the intelligent autocompletion and documentation of Kite, here how to deactivate Anaconda's autocompletion:

- https://help.kite.com/article/81-kite-and-anaconda

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of Kite. I am doing a number of things already in sublime and I was hoping to continue to use it for the docs as well for small python scripts.